# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and keyoard shortcuts

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, 14.04

I've recently installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Sony Vaio NS 21Z/S Laptop. I wanted to change the default mute combination from Fn+"Mute Key" to a special button. In preferences I've changed it. It detected the new button, but it doesn't work. After that I returned to the original combination and it doesn't work either. How can I fix it?

Best regards,

Mateusz

Comment: seems like a related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1313546

Answer (score 0):

Make the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
amixer set Master toggle
```

And bind it to your key.

Comment: Do I have to manually go set up all my shortcuts? Surely there should be a fix to fix all the shortcuts that stopped working.